# Ruby / Git library. How to get a full file of a particular check in?

Tags: ruby, git

Am working on a script based on git repository. Using ruby's git library.

Having trouble to find the feature to load the full file of a history check in. In git the content can be shown like:

```
git show 234h23h4j23l4j:path/to/file.java
```

Just need to know in ruby / git, how do I do that?

Note that this commit (234h23h4j23l4j) does not necessarily have the file I'm looking at.

Or if you know any other git library can easily do this please also recommend. We can still switch, it's not too late.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
commit = g.gcommit('1cc8667014381') #to get reference to some commit.
```

and then explore the commit object you get. (I found some [documentation here.](https://github.com/schacon/ruby-git))

Comment: Thanks. That's also the (only) page I've found. I forgot to mention the file I'm trying to get is not (necessarily) in the commit.